# RESTful webservice using Java Streams and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

I try to implement a RESTful WebService that is able to stream millions of records directly from database.
I'm using SpringBoot 2.2.5, Hibernate 5 and PostgreSQL 11

According to this post:
https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/spring-streams-memory-efficiency

one step is needed to set the flag "allowResultAccessAfterCompletion" to true.
But how can I do this in Spring Boot?

So far I do not have any SessionFactory, EntityManagerFactory, Datasource, ... configuration in my application. Everything is autoconfigured by SpringBoot.

If I add the proposed configuration below, the application won't start because of missing SessionFactory.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

  @Autowired @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(SessionFactory sf) {
    HibernateTransactionManager mgr = new HibernateTransactionManager(sf);
    mgr.setAllowResultAccessAfterCompletion(true);
    return mgr;
  }
  ... (the rest of your data config, including the LocalSessionFactoryBean) ...
}
```

If I provide a SessionFactory bean by unwrapping it from EntityManagerFactory, I get another exception:

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Does anyone have a working configuration for my setup?

Can't this flag simply be set by some configuration value in application.properties?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` maven dependency added in your pom.xml ? Also add appropriate keys (driver-class-name, username, password, url) in the `application.properties`/`application.yml`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to decide whether you need to use Hibernate or Spring JPA for your project. Work with the framework and not against it. Using jpa classes are preferred over hibernate classes by most people today.
Since you are using springboot , the best approach is to work with the framework and use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which will automatically configure all your necessary beans at startup. In that case, you could provide your own custom beans to override parameters as you want.

In the sample code that you provided in the question, you are using Hibernate classes directly , so you will have to manually create all the necessary beans as spring won't work with you for that unless you disable the auto-configurations which might be causing the circular dependency issue for you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.spring.repository")
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")

public class DataConfig {

    private final String PROPERTY_DRIVER = "driver";
    private final String PROPERTY_URL = "url";
    private final String PROPERTY_USERNAME = "user";
    private final String PROPERTY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private final String PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private final String PROPERTY_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        lfb.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.spring");
        lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
        return lfb;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setUrl(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_URL));
        ds.setUsername(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_USERNAME));
        ds.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_PASSWORD));
        ds.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_DRIVER));
        return ds;
    }

    Properties hibernateProps() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(PROPERTY_DIALECT, environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_DIALECT));
        properties.setProperty(PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL, environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and do not use any Hibernate classes directly.
Everything is running fine with spring boot autoconfiguration. I don't want to disable that.

The problem is, that I have to set the property "allowResultAccessAfterCompletion" of class HibernateTransactionManager to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well provide your own the SessionFactory as well in which case spring boot will not create another one for you. Following is excerpt from [Bootstrapping Hibernate 5 with Spring article](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring), feel free to tweak it as per your needs

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConf {
 
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
          {"com.baeldung.hibernate.bootstrap.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }
 
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("sa");
 
        return dataSource;
    }
 
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setAllowResultAccessAfterCompletion(true);
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
 
    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty(
          "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
 
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use [BeanPostProcessor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_post_processors.htm) if you know that spring boot is already creating a HibernateTransactionManager in it's own lifecycle. Following is what the outline of the this BeanPostProcessor would look like

```
public class HTMPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
   public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
      throws BeansException {
      if (bean instanceof HibernateTransactionManager) {
         ((HibernateTransactionManager)bean).setAllowResultAccessAfterCompletion(true);
      }
      return bean;  // you can return any other object as well
   }
   public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
      throws BeansException {
      return bean;  // you can return any other object as well
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, tried the approach using a BeanPostProcessor. But seems like i do not have a HibernateTransactionManger if i use JPA. A JpaTransactionManager has been instantiated, but on that i can not set the needed flag.